# Drawing a righthand coordinate system in mplot3d

Tags: matplotlib, coordinate-systems, mplot3d

I want to create plots from Python of 3D coordinate transformations. For example, I want to create the following image (generated statically by TikZ):

[image]

A bit of searching led me to the following program:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d


class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
arrow_prop_dict = dict(mutation_scale=20, arrowstyle='->', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)

a = Arrow3D([0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], **arrow_prop_dict, color='r')
ax.add_artist(a)
a = Arrow3D([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], **arrow_prop_dict, color='b')
ax.add_artist(a)
a = Arrow3D([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], **arrow_prop_dict, color='g')
ax.add_artist(a)

ax.text(0.0, 0.0, -0.1, r'$o$')
ax.text(1.1, 0, 0, r'$x$')
ax.text(0, 1.1, 0, r'$y$')
ax.text(0, 0, 1.1, r'$z$')

ax.view_init(azim=-90, elev=90)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

The result doesn't look like what one normally sees in books:

[image]

Furthermore, when I include the axes, the origin is not at the intersection of the three planes, which is where I expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you @moti!  I found the code in this question quite useful!

Comment: This nice example broke with matplotlib>=3.5. There is a fixed version in the issue here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21688.

Answer (score 1):

You may change the view of your 3D axes by changing the following line :

```
ax.view_init(azim=-90, elev=90)
```

to

```
ax.view_init(azim=20, elev=10)
```

to reproduce your TikZ plot, or change the view angles to any other values as you prefer.